# Cannot make R exclude NA cells

Tags: r, na, lme4

I am doing lmer and would like R to ignore `NA` cells. I have put this command:

```
lmer8 <- lmer(height ~ (1|item) + (1+|speaker) + color*sex, data=data4.frame,REML=FALSE,na.action=na.exclude)
```

However, in the summary of `lmer`, it still gives me the same number of rows (in the Number of obs) as the number of rows in excel original file, so it seems like the `NA` rows are not excluded in the formula. Do you have recommendations about this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I would double check that your data actually has NA values in it.

Comment: yeah there is. I use 'na' with lower case letters in my data. Should I use upper case ones instead?

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer to this question! It is because I specified 'no answer' as 'na' instead of 'NA' in .txt file. Oh, poor me. Sorry to bother you asking this stupid question. Now that formula with na.omit works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried na.omit instead of na.exclude? For some functions, the two are not interchangeable (for more information, see [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/missing.htm)).

Comment: I have found answer to this question! It is because I specified 'no answer' as 'na' instead of 'NA' in .txt file. Oh, poor me. Sorry to bother you asking this stupid question. Now that formula with na.omit works fine for me.